# Conditional expectation of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

In this question,
[Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process: Markov, but not martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730076/ornstein-uhlenbeck-process-markov-but-not-martingale)
, the process 
$$
 X_t = x e^{-\lambda t} + \sigma \int_0^t e^{-\lambda(t-s)} d W_s \,
$$
where $x$ is a constant and 
$ E[X_{t'} | \mathcal{F}_t]$, $0 \leq t < t'$
 is computed as 
$$
 E[X_{t'} | \mathcal{F}_t] = X_t e^{-\lambda {t'}} (\neq X_t) , \qquad 0 \leq t < t'
$$,
where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is generated by $W_t$.

Why is this?

I thought
\begin{align}
 E[X_{t'} | \mathcal{F}_t]
&=x e^{-\lambda t'}
+
E[\sigma \int_t^{t'} e^{-\lambda(t-s)} d W_s|\mathcal{F}_t]
+
E[\sigma \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\lambda(t-s)} d W_s|\mathcal{F}_t]\\
&=x e^{-\lambda t'}
+
0
+
\sigma \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\lambda(t-s)} d W_s\neq X_t,
\end{align}
where the second term is $0$ because of the independence, and the third term is due to the $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurability.

I understand $X$ is not martingale (well, if my calculation is correct), but don't understand why $ E[X_{t'} | \mathcal{F}_t]= X_t e^{-\lambda {t'}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing $X_t$ to $X_{t'}$ you need to change $t$ to $t'$ everywhere. Thus

\begin{align}
 E[X_{t'} | \mathcal{F}_t]
&=x e^{-\lambda t'}
+
E[\sigma \int_t^{t'} e^{-\lambda(t'-s)} d W_s|\mathcal{F}_t]
+
E[\sigma \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\lambda(t'-s)} d W_s|\mathcal{F}_t]\\
&=x e^{-\lambda t'}
+
0
+
\sigma \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\lambda(t'-s)} d W_s\neq X_t,
\\
&=e^{-\lambda (t'-t)}X_t
\end{align}
It seems the original computation was not correct or not correctly reported.